# How to avoid nested rxJS subscription

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I started a new Angular 7 project in which I need to call an API to get a list of results. Then if a specific result is in the list I select it, if not I create it calling another API endpoint. All of this stuff should be done into the `ngOnInit()` method.

To simplify the problem, I have the following code:

```js
const subject = new BehaviorSubject(null);
subject.next(6);

const res$ = subject.pipe(
  mergeMap(() => getValues()),
  tap((res) => {
    const exists = res.find(x => subject.value === x) || null;
    if (exists === null) {
      // TODO: call the getNew() function, but I don't want nested call
    } else {
      // Do nothing
    }
  })
);

// res$ should contains [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
res$.subscribe(x => console.log(x));

function getValues() {
  // Mocking the API call
  return of([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
}

function getNew() {
  // Mocking the API call
  return of(6);
}
```

At the end, the `res$` observable should contains all the array (with the added value) and I want to avoid nested subscription.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

1. Don't count on having access to the subject's value.  Instead you can you the alternative form of `mergeMap` which allows you to create a select the value from the source and new stream.  In this case I use it to return a new item down the stream with both the source and value from the inner observable.
2. You can use just another `mergeMap` to return either the original result or the result of the new api call by wrapping the orignal result in `of` to create a new inner observable.

```
const res$ = subject.pipe(
  mergeMap(x => getValues(), (orig, res) => ({ orig, res })),
  mergeMap(({ orig, res }) => {
    const exists = res.find(x => x === orig) || null;
    return (exists) 
      ? of(res)
      : getNew().pipe(map(x => [... res, x]))
  })
);
```

**[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-tfeh4s)**

Comment: Thank you, it is working!
Note that resultSelector is no longer supported in mergeMap, this is better to use inner map instead.
Use ```mergeMap(orig => getValues().pipe(map(res => ({orig, res})))),``` instead of ```mergeMap(x => getValues(), (orig, res) => ({ orig, res })),```

Comment: @youri - mind blown!  I use resultSelector a lot.  I feel it results in cleaner, flat, streams.  Oh well, thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

One way of solving this could be to split this up into two observables, and then combine them againg with combineLatest. We will use the resFirst$ observable twice, and filter it based on if it is null or not.

```
import { combineLatest } from 'rxjs';

---

const subject = new BehaviorSubject(null);
subject.next(6);

const resFirst$ = subject.pipe(
    mergeMap(() => getValues()),
    map((res) => res.find(x => subject.value === x) || null)
);

const resSecond$ = resFirst$.pipe(
    filter(exists => exists === null), <--- FILTERING FOR IS NULL
    mergeMap(() => getNew()) <--- SWITCHMAP COULD ALSO BE USED HERE DEPENDING ON WHAT YOU WANT
);

const final$ = combineLatest(resFirst$, resSecond$)
    .pipe(filter(exists => exists !== null)) <--- FILTERING FOR NOT NULL
    .subscribe(x => console.log(x));

function getValues() {
    // Mocking the API call
    return of([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
}

function getNew() {
    // Mocking the API call
    return of(6);
}
```